# php code or regex to replace position of characters in a string

Tags: php, css, regex

(Edit1: following George Cummins comment)I want you to help me  create a regex search and replace or a php function to replace position of characters in a string. (since i couldn't figure it out on my own)
Say I have the following CSS :

```
padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
```

And I want to make it:

```
padding: 1px 4px 3px 2px;
```

That is - to replace left and right padding.
Regardless to the actual numbers, and throughout my entire css style sheet

Can anyone help ?

Edit2: Solved By Jonathan Kuhn - Thank you ! also added an [imgur pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plnqp.png) of what it looks like in sublime text

Comment: What kind of inputs do you want to support? Just a single line which will always have 4 values?

Comment: _I want to create..._ != _I want you to create..._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
preg_replace('/padding: (\d+px) (\d+px) (\d+px) (\d+px);/', 'padding: $1 $4 $3 $2;', $css);
```

Comment: **That worked beautifully !**    here is an [image](http://i.imgur.com/6uNtiXs.png) of what I did in sublime text if anyone would need it later